# i2c /IIC 20x04 lcd not displaying text

Tags: python, i2c, lcd

I have an 20x4 LCD and an i2c /IIC interface. If connected to the raspberry pi zero w, it looks the following:
[image: 20x4 lcd display with 2 lined fully filled]
And from the back it looks like this:
[image: back of display, icc/i2c module with power led not showing]
Interestingly, the power led of the icc/i2c module is not on.

I have used the code from [this tutorial](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.de/hd44780-lcd-display-per-i2c-mit-dem-raspberry-pi-ansteuern/), although the tutorial is in german, the code is the necessary part I belive.

This is the test code I'm runnning:

```
import lcddriver
from time import *

lcd = lcddriver.lcd()
lcd.lcd_clear()

lcd.lcd_backlight("OFF")
sleep(1)
lcd.lcd_backlight("ON")

lcd.lcd_display_string("test1", 1)
lcd.lcd_display_string("      test2", 2)
lcd.lcd_display_string("       test3", 3)
lcd.lcd_display_string("            test4", 4)
```

the display background led turns off and on again as wished, but text is not showing.
What could possibly be wrong?

Edit:
I noticed that I use the PCF8574t  as a backpack i2c interface, maybe this is important with the library compatibility used?

Comment: Did anything show up at the i2cdetect command?

Comment: yes, there is a 27. And the display background LED is controllable

Comment: Possibly a contrast problem.  Try twiddling a screwdriver in the blue pot to see if that reveals any text.

Comment: Thank you joan. I saw the posts of the contrast problems and already sorted this out.

Comment: Solution: It was not properly soldered